# Machines keep using power

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-industrialcraft

Some machines tend to be "always on" and constantly draw energy from my batboxes that get fed by fossil fuel. It took me a while (and thus many stacks of coal) to find out that these machines keep draining my energy. Some machines that do this are:

- Electric Heat Generator
- Electric Kinetic Generator

Is there anything that I can do that will prevent this, apart from removing the cable? A switch does not seem to work but there must be a way to turn these machines "off" somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electric Heat Generators use Coil to generate Heat Units (HU)
Electric Kinetic Generators use Electric Motor to generate Kinetic Units (KU)

When they are not hooked to anything they shouldn't consume any power.  But if what they are connected to can consume the Heat or Kinetic energy, then they will constantly draw power.

You can:

- Use EU-Splitter Cable in place of one of the power cables will allow you interrupt power to that machine or any machines further down the line by applying a redstone signal to the cable.  You know this works because the normal cable on either side will become disconnected from the splitter.
- Remove the Coil or Electric Motors from the inventory of the machines.  Without the items used to generate the energy they won't consume power.

Comment: Or you can use redstone behaviour of Batboxes.

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch cable between your power storage unit(batbox/cesu/mfe/mfsu) output and the ones that connected to the machine then apply redstone signal to it to stop eu flow from powersource.

Comment: NEI does not find `Switch Cable`.

Comment: The IC2 site has an entry for [Switch Cable](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Switch_Cable), but it's not listed in the "IndustrialCraft² Stuff" box below. Maybe it's outdated. The [Splitter Cable](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Splitter_Cable) is, and it seems to have this functionality, you can try that. I just noticed that the crafting recipe for both is the same, too.